# How to implement a general Mime type correctly in PHP?

Tags: php

If you click view,you'll open that file in browser,

I've tried :

```
readfile('test.jpg');
```

But seems it fails in firefox.

Comment: Can you define "it fails" ? Do you get an error message, for instance ? Is the file present (and in the current directory) ?

Comment: It gives me lots of messy characters instead of an image.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the mime-type for a file, you have at least two options, in PHP :

The first one is to use the (now deprecated) function [`mime_content_type`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) :

> Returns the content type in MIME
>   format, like `text/plain` or
>   `application/octet-stream`.

The second would be to use the new [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) extension *(Available as a PECL extension for PHP < 5.3, and integrated in PHP >= 5.3)* ; the [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function seems to be the one you'll need :

> Returns a textual description of the
>   contents of the filename argument, or
>   FALSE if an error occurred.

And the given example *(quoting)* :

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Gives this kind of output :

```
text/html
image/gif
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Which kind of corresponds to what you'll need to use for the `Content-type` HTTP header that your application might need to send ;-)

Comment: If there are many concurrent users you might want to consider caching the result somehow since mime magic pattern testing isn't the "cheapest" of functions ;-)

Comment: Well, there is some kind of "magic database" you have to put in the right place (I tried a couple of times, it's not that easy to set up, but not **that** hard either) ;; there are a couple of informations on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php that might guide you a bit farther.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a link to that file and browser will do the rest. If this file is stored on your server you're probably looking for a script that will expose it to the outer world. This script should set up the correct MIME type and then `readfile` should do the trick.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/gif');
readfile('/path/to.your/file.gif');
exit();
```

Comment: What if the file is .pdf?Is there a general solution?